# Install internal failed

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I built my app using jfxmobile, but got an error during installation on device. Not sure what's the problem.

jfxmobile-plugin version: 2.0.29

```
> Task :launchIOSDevice
[19:54:40:063] BosonAppSupport: Validating codesign... 
[SUB] /Entwicklung/sibvisions/jvxfxmobile/trunk/java/DemoERP/build/gvm/DemoERP.mobile.app: valid on disk
[SUB] /Entwicklung/sibvisions/jvxfxmobile/trunk/java/DemoERP/build/gvm/DemoERP.mobile.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
[19:54:40:685] BosonAppSupport: Validation codesign result: true 
[19:54:40:685] BosonAppSupport: Codesign done 
[19:54:40:805] BosonAppBuilder: UploadInternal start 
[19:54:41:940] : Upload Progress: 10% 
[19:54:43:014] : Upload Progress: 20% 
[19:54:43:460] : Upload Progress: 30% 
[19:54:48:388] : Upload Progress: 40% 
[19:54:49:512] : Upload Progress: 50% 
[19:54:50:621] : Upload Progress: 60% 
[19:54:51:544] : Upload Progress: 70% 
[19:54:52:670] : Upload Progress: 80% 
[19:54:53:860] : Upload Progress: 90% 
[19:54:55:094] : Upload Progress: 100% 
[19:54:55:167] BosonAppBuilder: uploadInternal done 

[19:54:55:554] : Progress: CreatingStagingDirectory [5%] 
[19:54:55:555] : Progress: ExtractingPackage [15%] 
[19:54:55:555] : Progress: InspectingPackage [20%] 
[19:54:55:562] : Progress: TakingInstallLock [20%] 
[19:54:55:565] : Progress: PreflightingApplication [30%] 
[19:54:55:583] : Progress: InstallingEmbeddedProfile [30%] 
[19:54:55:585] : Progress: VerifyingApplication [40%] 
[19:54:55:735] : Error: APIInternalError 

> Task :launchIOSDevice
[19:54:55:735] BosonAppBuilder: Installing finished due to an error. 
[19:54:55:737] BosonAppBuilder: Install internal failed 
[19:54:55:737] BosonAppBuilder: Something went wrong. App wasn't installed on the device
```

Comment: Typically this error at 40% happens either when you don't have a valid provisioning profile and you can't sign the app, or when there is something wrong with the app, like having a mismatch between the bundleID name indicated in the plist file and the name of the project. Make sure you double check it.

Comment: The provisioning profile is working with another simple demo app. So I'll check the bundleID.

Comment: You're right. The CFBundleExecutable in the plist was not the same as the rootProject.name in settings.gradle. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint of José solved the problem - see comments!